# Unable to delete a file from repository in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using Mercurial(TortoiseHG) as version-control system for our source code. I am unable to remove a file from the repository, from the command-line. I see several people on web, giving solutions like:
1. hg rm 
2. hg remove

These commands do the operation of removal from the directory. However, when I pull the repository at a seperate place, the above file(supposed to be deleted) still shows up. I tried pusing the repo after performing the above commands as well, with:
hg push

But the files are not really removed from the repository. Do I need to configure anything extra for this removal operation?

Comment: Did you commit and push after deleting the file? Is the file tracked by the repository in the first place?

Comment: after deleting the file, i won't have the file in the directory. so, i din't commit it. however, i pushed that repository from command-line. yes, the file is tracked by the repository.

Comment: If you didn't commit, then the file is still in the repository, just not in your working folder, so no wonder it didn't disappear in other clones. You need to ask mercurial to forget the file, or use the delete command of mercurial to delete it, then commit, then push, then pull in other clones and update. Only then will the file disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I generally have the habit of committing at the leaf-level, and thus wasn't committing the root repo folder all the while. Sorry for the miscommunication.